# Unknown data payload

Tags: python, python-requests

Im trying to make requests to proxy.webshare.io/register to generate account but i meet this in requests payload and idk what it means:

```
csrfmiddlewaretoken: ph8vDjVsCqtMlZBNaw7w3udZfiFovmhUD6iwoYX4lUvCnaWuyH4371eaP7h2b6rg
next: 
a: a338db2062a111f4279647be78177f5d700bae080c7222dde6f7dc9d88480c25
email: adklasdlklkasdhasdi@gmail.com
password1: ádaiysdauisdh
g-recaptcha-response: 03ANYolqtAmlYpxhm9kYEJEeTOwNAWeei2G8oa4_W16vPP11n8hyQNCuMYNHVXNj0ppxPSZHLrA26T_7s7BEdWxhS4pLtBse42k5Q5PQoGvQBfM_9SN9Wyrs4CI04lgKjUYTz5wTq_d4tt6vwQK0WkR1K2H34cLaFtxTGv6ugeuzcBmIgOqHLGKUkfOUzgpBpCQ8XFMrV6UeNG1o3jzJa3fnKbCSolvvm7mDh6zE0XZDHVYX2xQPvJNCcyeUGUKnQ1AM1zEW7Lk7PzMFBZT8w0p57LKGVw-50ZXH2Y4nF1Vjnu4-PWVC30l61BbP_PxAVw15df499g6ABLy9LFhpKJdX6o8aKr5XmhkF5_xDm5rLDEnMMhBnsfWzit6ZSBinKC4UyaLlOE2Y32cuLuIGRM9PIy1jKz6D2pnhwGE2243Q0VmC4Gyl9S9UPlUp6wD-uWq_mXlgGxQYUXTvhYE8f-TtJLiLkCXNYrsf2EzQMaB0BwpbsO1EgBM3X1Vl2ImP_e4ckpHN-YANwfPF9INp_dMZCW6Le8LIc0_M7FjYw6oMhvkTuxSndHDU8
```

idk what is the a mean can anyone help me please?
what i have done so far:

```
    captcha = RecaptchaV2Task("f45d75eba65f912dcdd84c6fb982db83")
    em_f_n = "".join(random.choices(string.ascii_letters, k=15))
    pw_f_n = "".join(random.choices(string.ascii_letters + string.digits, k=15))
    def _solve_recaptcha():
        task_id = captcha.create_task(website_url="https://proxy.webshare.io/register/", website_key="6LeHZ6UUAAAAAKat_YS--O2tj_by3gv3r_l03j9d")
        print("Wait for respone")
        print(task_id)
        respone = captcha.join_task_result(task_id).get("gRecaptchaResponse")
        print("Recieved key: " + respone)

        return respone
    key = _solve_recaptcha()
    if 'csrftoken' in client.cookies:
        csrftoken = client.cookies['csrftoken']
    else:
        csrftoken = client.cookies['csrf']
    data = {
    "email": f"{em_f_n}@gmail.com",
    "password1": pw_f_n,
    "g-recaptcha-response": key,
    "next": "/",
    "csrfmiddlewaretoken":csrftoken
    }
    
    r = client.post("https://proxy.webshare.io/register", json=data)
    print(r.status_code)
    print(em_f_n+ "@gmail.com")
    print(pw_f_n)
    time.sleep(2)
```

Im trying to create account in proxy.webshare.io/register in requests
[image: original payload image]

Comment: Please share some code and describe what you have done so far, and what the payload is a result of / what you expect.

Comment: ok i will add some

Comment: @TobiasP.G. i have add can u help me please?

Answer (score 0):

It is the POST data/body when you send a POST request. If you compare the keys from the data dictionary in your code it is identical to the payload shown in the browser.

This was supposed to be a comment, but I have less than 50 reputation.